# Refresh Visual Studio Code list of files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code (Version 0.10.11, on OSX) does not refresh the files in a folder.  Is there any way to force it to refresh.  Currently I have to close and reopen the whole program.

Comment: Here's the [Github issue for this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28432).

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**EDIT: In the meanwhile a reload button has been added to the file explorer widget.**

Use the `workbench.action.reloadWindow` command. 
Go to `File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shotcuts` and define a shortcut for this command. On my system it's placed on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. The entry in `keybindings.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+f5",
  "command": "workbench.action.reloadWindow",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: You just need to refresh the file explorer, either click on the circle arrow in the top of the file explorer ([see this screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9638156/35730124-f92b1dd2-0821-11e8-9fc1-ac471805a3b7.png)) or use a keyboard shortcut ([see @jack-click's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549061/1168315)).

Comment: It reloads whole window, the question was about reloading only list of files in the explorer.

Comment: I searched settings for "workbench.action.reloadWindow" and it returned 35 settings, none of which seem to be what I wanted. The screenshot really helped!

Comment: This closes all the open terminals; all the build, test, test coverage tools. Not a good solution effectivly restarting the app; this should not be the correct answer; This is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48547570/1551184

Answer (score 93):

If you hover over the workspace root in the navigator, four icons appear to the right of it.  The third of those icons, a circular arrow, is **Refresh** -- it reloads the file list.

[image]

Comment: The hovering behaviour in my version (1.41.1 on mac osx) is a bit odd:
1: You can bring it up by hovering over any of the nodes in the workspace panel.
2: It will also appear without hovering if you select the workspace line itself
3: Hovering won't work at all if the workspace panel is collapsed such that you only see the header

Answer (score 63):

You can use the command palette to reload the window:

1. Open the command palette with **View** > **Command Palette...** (or **Shift+Cmd+P** on OS X)
2. Type `reload window` and press enter

Comment: This closes all the open terminals; all the build, test, test coverage tools. Not a good solution for me

Comment: **Ctrl+Shift+P** on Windows

Comment: In my case I'm using Ubuntu and this option works fine without closing the openm terminals (ctrl+shif+P) -> reload

Great!

Answer (score 37):

You shouldn't need to reload the entire window, just the folder list. Reloading the window will kill terminals, lose undo history, etc. You can do this using the refresh button in the explorer (second from the right):

[image]

If you find you need to do this a lot you can add a keybinding for it, for example:

```js
{
  "key": "ctrl+f5",
  "command": "workbench.files.action.refreshFilesExplorer"
}
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? It is just the files, not the window!

Answer (score 11):

Ran across this today with VS Code 1.13.0 and in Keyboard Shortcuts I see

```
workbench.files.action.refreshFilesExplorer
```

Answer (score 2):

To reload a single file:

- ⇧⌘P
- type "Revert File"

On Windows:

- Ctrl + Shift + P
- type "Revert File"

Tested in VSCode v1.18.1 on Windows

Answer (score 2):

If you use the SFTP extension you can do this for refreshing the SFTP:EXPLORER list (tested on Windows with VSC 1.40.2):

File => Preferences => Keyboard Shortcuts => Search for: refresh

Then you have to find "Refresh / sftp.remoteExplorer.refresh" in the result list.
Click the entry, then click the plus sign before the entry, then press your desired shortcut and hit "enter". I took "Ctrl + Alt + F5" because this has not been used for other commands already.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click your sln (Will say 0/n solutions)
In the bottom row of dialog it will say reload project solutions.
If it's not present, then it was just reloaded most likely. Try to run build again.

Answer (score 0):

When `search.maintainFileSearchCache` option is enabled I started to find the files with I'm using `Ctrl-P` shortcut

[image]

Answer (score -4):

"Ctrl + Alt + R" on v 1.27.1 as of 9/11/18

Comment: Add some description\