# How to refresh content of opened files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to refresh the content of a file opened in editor after it was changed by other tool.

For instance I'm using angular command line which makes changes to files but VS Code doesn't refresh the content after that and I can't see any of that. What's worse when I try to save the file, VS Code by default tries to save the old content upon the newer (asks before of course, but still its not what I'm looking for).

I didn't find any keybindings for refresh the editor's content. Maybe there are any extensions?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out this plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotnetricardo.Reload

Comment: Thank you but this extension unfortunately is about refreshing browser, Im looking for extension or built-in for refreshing an opened content of a file in the editor.

Comment: Ok what about changing the hotkey like this guy suggests in his answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333117/refresh-visual-studio-code-list-of-files

Comment: Best answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002990/908936

Comment: If https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/186976#issue-1787728566 is upvoted 20 times, this will become possible because the feature will be moved to VSCode's backlog.

Answer (score 5):

It should reload itself automatically, but I had a machine that stopped auto-refreshing. I'd change the file externally (with vim or whatever), and the file I had in the editor wouldn't *pop* and refresh itself, which it used to do. It turned out to be a git-related extension. I disabled it, and autorefresh returned. If you haven't already, try it with extensions off.

Comment: Yes, it should reload and most of the the times it does in fact, but in some situations (I didn't recognized exactly when yet) it doesn't and those moments the option to reload it by key shortcut would be efficient at least...

Comment: On a Mac, I could force a refresh from the keyboard by hitting ctrl-tab twice, which switches to another open file and then switches back. I did this briefly before I discovered that the extension was preventing auto-refresh. Also, double-check that you haven't accidentally excluded this file type from auto-refresh by checking `files.watcherExclude` in preferences.

Answer (score 2):

keybindings.json

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f5",
    "command": "workbench.action.files.revert",
  },
```

This will reload the focused file from disk.
(Warning: Any unsaved changes on the focused file will be lost.)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the command palette (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `p`) and execute the command `Reload Window` as per [this blog post](https://www.graef.io/how-to-reload-vscode-window/).

I use this when I create dynamic charts inside jupyter notebooks and want to take a screenshot at high resolution. Zooming in (`Ctrl` + `+`) first renders the charts blurry, but after reloading the window, the charts will re-render at higher resolution just as they would in a browser (as long as you use a chart library that is aware of the window zoom).